# IOS custom segue Up to Down

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I want to create a custom segue that vertically goes from up to down instead of down to up.

This is not shown in the Attributes inspector.The segue gets called when the user swipes down but the next view-controller slides up.instead of swiping down.
I have named my segue "Segue" (I know How original!)

However, I am not sure what to write and which file to write it in.Do I make a different class file?
[image][image]

Comment: I think this is a good question no matter your age, so I upvoted it. (Didn't check for dups though.) I've found that - pretty much - anything you can do in code you also can in IB. Unfortunately I'm not one who uses IB! That said, maybe you could subclass `UIStoryboardSegue`, code things to do what you need, and set the pictured segue to be *that* subclass? That's my only suggestion.